# Why this image access loading error on a Promise script fiddle?

Tags: javascript, image, xmlhttprequest, jsfiddle

I'm using a Promise to load an image in a fiddle and keep getting an access error. I've tried a variety of images - posted to dropbox, placeholders, and others, but all are blocked. What can I use/do that will work? I believe the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3595515/2441384) are relevant, but am having trouble connecting the dots.

Here is the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7ptcure9tlw8pl/Pensive%20Parakeet.jpg?dl=0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm using the fiddle to practice writing Promises to get my head around them, and have borrowed the script [here](http://mdn.github.io/promises-test/) to practice on. My fiddle in question is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/wh41m63c/).

Comment: The problem is you are tying to do a cross-origin request and dropbox isn't allowing it. The url also points towards a text/html resource and not the image itself.

Comment: @MinusFour - Thanks! Is there a resource that will work? ...or do I need to do my experiments locally rather than on JSFiddle?

Comment: If you try it with a real image and a site that allows cross-origin requests it [**works**](https://jsfiddle.net/wh41m63c/8/).

Comment: @MinusFour - Excellent, thanks! If you write up an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in my comment that URL from dropbox doesn't allow cross-origin requests plus the resource isn't an image (it's actually html). If you use images from a site that allows cross-origin requests (like `imgur` for example) then it works.

```js
function imgLoad(url) {
    // Create new promise with the Promise() constructor;
    // This has as its argument a function
    // with two parameters, resolve and reject
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // Standard XHR to load an image
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', url);
      request.responseType = 'blob';

      // When the request loads, check whether it was successful
      request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
        // If successful, resolve the promise by passing back the request response
          resolve(request.response);
        } else {
        // If it fails, reject the promise with a error message
          reject(Error('Image didn\'t load successfully; error code:' + request.statusText));
        }
      };

      request.onerror = function() {
      // Also deal with the case when the entire request fails to begin with
      // This is probably a network error, so reject the promise with an appropriate message
          reject(Error('There was a network error.'));
      };

      // Send the request
      request.send();
    });
  }

  // Get a reference to the body element, and create a new image object
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  var myImage = new Image();

  // Call the function with the URL we want to load, but then chain the
  // promise then() method on to the end of it. This contains two callbacks
  imgLoad('https://i.imgur.com/Kusegys.jpg').then(function(response) {
    // The first runs when the promise resolves, with the request.reponse
    // specified within the resolve() method.
    var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
    myImage.src = imageURL;
    body.appendChild(myImage);
    // The second runs when the promise
    // is rejected, and logs the Error specified with the reject() method.
  }, function(Error) {
    console.log(Error);
  });
```

```css
img {
    height:1125px;
    width:750px;
}
```